# SQL select query order by adding two field performance

Tags: mysql, sql

consider two sql queries

```
select a+b absum from my_table order by a+b;
select absum from (select a+b absum from my_table) order by absum;
```

Is there any difference regarding performance?
I wonder how the SQL execute the query: will it calculate a+b once or twice? And is there any performance improving trick?

Comment: Look at the explain plan. Try the query and see if you see a performance difference. But the explain plan will give you the most information.

Comment: I think the second one is going to have to materialize the subquery but I may be wrong. You can get the execution plans for both and compare.

Comment: Why don't you write `select a+b absum from my_table order by absum`?

Comment: @Barmar - How will that help in terms of performance?

Comment: @GurV It might not have to do the addition twice. But even if it makes no difference, it's a little clearer IMHO.

Comment: Basically who knows what the optimizer will do try it using explain and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me point out that looking at the explain output is really important for understanding these things.  However, it can answer the question only for a specific query, and not in general -- the optimizer might choose different ways of executing the query based on other factors.

In MySQL -- and pretty much only in MySQL -- there is a difference in performance, at least until 5.7.

The biggest reason is that MySQL materializes the subquery, and then does the sort.  In this case, the overhead of materialization is not very large, because the sort is going to dominate the performance.

There are cases where the performance would be much larger -- sometimes materialization prevents the use of indexes and partitions.

However in MySQL 5.7, the optimizer introduced "merging", which is an alternative method for handling subqueries.  This method allows the compiler to ignore the subquery -- and ignore the additional materialization.

These concepts *are* explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html); it does help if you have some familiarity with what the database compiler/optimizer does.